# React-Router-Dom v6 How do I match subpages. I was on v5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I found that I am having to reorganize my routes switching from React-Router-Dom v5 to v6.

I have this outer route:

```
<Route
  path="/abc/product/:skuType/:skuPage?"
  element={
    <PrivateRoute>
      <ProductRoutesStructure />
    </PrivateRoute>
  }
/>
```

But none of my routes are matching. So I am unsure how to match. For instance, in one route, it looks like this: `'abc/product/1234/converse'`

and I am doing this:

```
export const ProductRoutesStructure = () => (
  <Routes key="productRoutes">
    <Route
      path={`/abc/product/:skuType/:skuPage(${Types.CONVERSE})`} 
      element={<SneakerPage />}
    />
    <Route
      path={`/abc/product/:skuType/:skuPage(${Types.PANTS})`} 
      element={<PantsPage />}
    />
    <Route path="*" element={<GenericPage />} />
  </Routes>
)
```

The things is that `skuType` and `skuPage` must be dyanmic as in those `element` components since I hit certain APIs. I just am really needing to match on the `skuPage`.

I think I am missing some nuance of sub pages. I tried matching on just "Types.CONVERSE", but that is a no go, it always defaults to the last bit `"*"` catch-all route.

This is what I am expecting and this most certainly worked in v5, as this is actual code I used (pathing is different/names). But exactly the same. Worked like a charm, but v6, nope.

So, if a user goes to `"www.myDomain/abc/product/male/converse"`

I expect that to match this route:

```
<Route
  path={`/abc/product/:skuType/:skuPage(${Types.CONVERSE})`} 
 element={<SneakerPage />}
/>
```

If a user goes to `"www.myDomain/abc/product/female/pants"`

It would match:

```
<Route
  path={`/abc/product/:skuType/:skuPage(${Types.PANTS})`}
  element={<PantsPage />}
/>
```

But lets just make it work. I have no problem altering my routes in `ProductRoutesStructure`, but I tried a bunch of combinations, and nothing is matching.

Mind you, I do need `skuType` and `skuPage` to be available to child components/pages, that is why I need it in the base route.

Comment: You have literal parentheses in the path, don't you? `/abc/product/:skuType/:skuPage(${Types.CONVERSE})` is going to match `"/abc/product/foo/bar(converse)"`.

Comment: `"/abc/product/:skuType/:skuPage(.......)"` isn't a valid path to match, you can't do partial matches, so only the `"*"` is matchable. Can you [edit] to clarify what route path values you are actually trying to match here? Something like `"/abc/product/:skuType/converse"` or `"/abc/product/:skuType/pants"`?

Comment: @DrewReese In version 5, I was most certainly able to partial match. Has that changed, if so, wow... v6 is terrible. How do I get around this? Btw, I updated my question. in relation to your question. It would match both.. and each would display their respective components listed in "element"

Comment: Affirmative, to the partial matches... RRDv6 is great otherwise. See the [Dynamic Segments](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#dynamic-segments) section, read down a bit. From what you say is the route path you want to match though, those aren't partial paths. Am I correct in reading the route that you are trying to have `skuPage` as a route path parameter, limited to the value in parenthesis, that you can access in the routed component via the `useParams` hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you have basically this `"/abc/product/:skuType/:skuPage"` route path that you'd like to match and render dynamic content on.

### Suggestion 1

Render a single `"/abc/product/:skuType/:skuPage"` route and use a regular old Javascript `switch` statement to conditionally render the correct routed content based on the `skuPage` route path parameter.

Outer Route

```
<Routes>
  <Route
    path="/abc/product/:skuType/:skuPage"
    element={
      <PrivateRoute>
        <ProductRoutesStructure />
      </PrivateRoute>
    }
  />
</Routes>
```

ProductsRoutesStructure

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const ProductRoutesStructure = () => {
  const { skuPage } = useParams();

  switch (skuPage) {
    case Types.CONVERSE:
      return <SneakerPage />;

    case Types.PANTS:
      return <PantsPage />;

    default:
      return <GenericPage />;
  }
};
```

The routed content components use the `useParams` hook to access their route parameters.

```
const SneakerPage = () => {
  const { skuPage, skuType } = useParams();

  return (
    <>
      <h1>SneakerPage</h1>
      <div>{skuType} - {skuPage}</div>
    </>
  );
};

const PantsPage = () => {
  const { skuPage, skuType } = useParams();

  return (
    <>
      <h1>PantsPage</h1>
      <div>{skuType} - {skuPage}</div>
    </>
  );
};
```

#### Demo 1

[image: Edit react-react-dom-v6-how-do-i-match-subpages-i-was-on-v5]

[image]

### Suggestion 2

Render each specific `skuPage` directly, passing the `skuPage` value down as props to the routed content components.

Outer Route

```
<Routes>
  <Route
    path="/abc/product/:skuType/*" // <-- wildcard matcher for descendent routes
    element={
      <PrivateRoute>
        <ProductRoutesStructure />
      </PrivateRoute>
    }
  />
</Routes>
```

ProductRoutesStructure

```
const ProductRoutesStructure = () => (
  <Routes key="productRoutes">
    <Route
      path={Types.CONVERSE}
      element={<SneakerPage skuPage={Types.CONVERSE} />}
    />
    <Route path={Types.PANTS} element={<PantsPage skuPage={Types.PANTS} />} />
    <Route path="*" element={<GenericPage />} />
  </Routes>
);
```

```
const SneakerPage = ({ skuPage }) => {
  const { skuType } = useParams();

  return (
    <>
      <h1>SneakerPage</h1>
      <div>
        {skuType} - {skuPage}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

const PantsPage = ({ skuPage }) => {
  const { skuType } = useParams();

  return (
    <>
      <h1>PantsPage</h1>
      <div>
        {skuType} - {skuPage}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

#### Demo 2

[image: Edit react-react-dom-v6-how-do-i-match-subpages-i-was-on-v5(version 2)]

[image]

Comment: Is either preferred?

Comment: @jamesemanon That's subjective, and even for me it's 50/50. They are both about the same amount of code, have about the same level of readability and maintainability. I don't think I can say there's an industry "preference" for one over the other.

Comment: thanks a bunch. Appreciate your willingness to help. Kudos!